# Accessing common properties from multiple python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not entirely sure if the title is appropriate for this question but here's what I am trying to achieve:
I have a directory structure like this:

```
models/
   modelA/
      src/
         modelA.py
      __init__.py
   modelB/
      src/
          modelB.py
      __init__.py
scripts/
   sandbox.py
```

The `__init__.py` file within each model folder contains the following code:

```
from .src.modelA import modelA as Model

MODEL_NAME = "modelA"
MODEL_VERSION = "1.0.0"

INPUT_FEATURES_TYPES = [ ("feature1", "1.0.0"), ("feature2", "1.0.0") ]
INPUT_TYPE = "images"
```

Now from within sandbox.py, I want to be able to create an array containing the list of models and their properties by parsing each of the `__init__.py` files. The final result I want to achieve is something like this:

```
[{
    name : "modelA",
    version: "1.0.0",
    inputFeat : [("feature1", "1.0.0"), ("feature2", "1.0.0")],
    inputType : "images"
 }, 
 {
    name : "modelB",
    version: "1.0.0",
    inputFeat : [("feature1", "1.0.0"), ("feature2", "1.0.0")],
    inputType : "text"
 },
 ...
]
```

Is there any easy way to do this? or do I HAVE to create and update a static file that lists all these details? My intention is that I can keep adding new models in the future and still be able to easily extract this list whenever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pkgutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages) to iterate over the submodules:

```
import pkgutil
import importlib

for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules('/path/to/models', '.src.'):
   module = importlib.import_module(modname)
   from module import MODEL_NAME, MODEL_VERSION, INPUT_FEATURES_TYPES, INPUT_TYPE
```

Then you can create your dictionary.

I haven't tested the previous code but it works on one my own packages using the module name:

`pkgutil.iter_modules(module.__path__, module.__name__ + '.')`

Comment: This has almost solved my problem but I don't understand this behaviour:

`for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__):`
    `if (ispkg):`
        `print(prefix + modname)`
        `model = __import__(prefix + modname)`
        `print(model)`

The output is: `aiscripts.models.geom_resnet`
`<module 'aiscripts' (namespace)>`
`aiscripts.models.some_model`
`<module 'aiscripts' (namespace)>`

It PRINTS the correct submodule but imports only the top level module. So I cannot access the properties of the submodule!

Comment: Have you tried adding the prefix to the iter_module function like I did: `pkgutil.iter_modules(module.__path__, module.__name__ + '.')`

Comment: Yes I did. The same result. The modname is correct but only the top level module is actually imported.

Comment: Try `model = __import__(prefix+modname, fromlist='dummy')`

Comment: Or you might want to use: `importlib.import_module('prefix+modname')`

Comment: okay so I checked the docs and the behaviour of `__import__` is to infact import the top level module. So I had to use `import_module()` function and that solved my problem. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: thanks for the help! Marked as the accepted answer!